# Problems with async in Promises

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm getting a problem with a Promise. I'm not getting the answer because the async. Well, I think thats the problem because when I run the code I'm not getting any kind of error but I'm not getting also any answer.

This is my code

```
'use strict'

import validator from "validator"
import cassandra from "./cassandra";
import timezone from "./timezone"
import requestRace from "./request"

exports.getUser = (req, res)  =>  {
  const getHistory =  `SELECT inscriptionid,first_name,created,lastupdate,number,eventraceid ` +
                      `FROM inscription_data ` +
                      `WHERE userid = ${req.params.idUser} ` +
                    //  `AND number IS NOT NULL ` +
                      `ALLOW FILTERING`;
  if(req.params && validator.isUUID(req.params.idUser))  {
    cassandra.execute(getHistory)
      .then(ans  => {
          requestRace(timezone(ans.rows))
            .then(aws => console.log("hola"))
            .catch(err => console.log("error: ", err))
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(500).json({code: 500,data:{error: true,message: err}}))
  }
}
```

and this other one

```
'use strict'

import axios from "axios"

const route = `https://ms.***.com/v1/races/`

function requestRace(params)  {
  var newArr = new Array(), newObj = {}, hola
  params.map(obj => {
    axios.get(`${route}${obj['eventraceid']}?apikey=pub_nLbIjlCWNKAdB_O3qgTaoQ`)
      .then(res => {
        newArr.push(creaJSON(obj, res.data))
    //    console.log("New:", newArr)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log("error: ", err))
  })
 return newArr.then(ho => {return ho} )
}

function creaJSON(obj,subojb) {
  obj['race'] = subojb[`data`]
  return obj
}


module.exports = requestRace
```

If anyone can see my error I will appreciate if you can explain where is my error and why

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: By "not getting an answer" I assume you mean that the server isn't sending a response? Well of course you're missing this, nothing in your code is doing that (you only send a response in the error case).

Comment: Think about what happens WHEN in your code. If you go shopping _before_ the stores open - of course you won't get anything. Time matters, not just place. The same place may or may not have what you want at different times. Think about `newArr.push` in the 2nd function for example. What is it, and how do you use it? There is a mismatch. Think about it step by step, this looks too random(ly constructed code).  YOu also should reconsider your use of `map` - it is supposed to be used to construct new arrays.

Comment: thank you @Mörre I found my error and I fixed with async/await. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

To fix my problem I had to use async/await. This is how it ended

```
'use strict'

import validator from "validator"
import cassandra from "./cassandra";
import timezone from "./timezone"
import requestRace from "./request"

exports.getUser = (req, res)  =>  {
  const getHistory =  `SELECT inscriptionid,first_name,created,lastupdate,number,eventraceid ` +
                      `FROM inscription_data ` +
                      `WHERE userid = ${req.params.idUser} ` +
                      `AND number IS NOT NULL ` +
                      `ALLOW FILTERING`;
  if(req.params && validator.isUUID(req.params.idUser))  {
    cassandra.execute(getHistory)
      .then(ans  => {
          requestRace(timezone(ans.rows))
            .then(aws => res.status(200).json({code:200, data:aws}))
            .catch(err => console.log("error: ", err))
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(500).json({code: 500,data:{error: true,message: err}}))
  }
}
```

'use strict'

```
import axios from "axios"

const route = `http://***/v1/inscription/`

async function requestRace(params)  {
    var newArr = new Array(), newObj = {}
    for(let p in params)  {
      await axios.get(`${route}${params[p]['inscriptionid']}?apikey=pub_nLbIjlCWNKAdB_O3qgTaoQ`)
        .then(res => {
          newArr.push(creaJSON(params[p], res.data))
        }).then(ok => {return ok})
        .catch(err => console.log("error: ", err))
    }

  return newArr
}

function creaJSON(obj,subojb) {
  obj['race'] = subojb[`data`]
  return obj
}


module.exports = requestRace
```

Comment: Maybe the next generation of programmers will find "await in a loop" preferable to the *old-fashioned* `return Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)`, which delivers an array of results automatically without the need for an ugly `var newArr = []`.

Comment: In catches that exist only to log an error, either (a) propagate the error by rethrowing it, or (b) return some default value/object to take the place of the missing result.

Comment: As @Roamer-1888 said - don't use `await` in a loop (you serialize what could run in parallel) -- and you also should not mix promises (`then`/`catch`) and `await`. Use one or the other, unless there is something that cannot be expressed otherwise.

Comment: @Mörre, "serialize what could run in parallel" - good point, I missed that one.